# Pass object to directives without watching them

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Generally we use the `=` to make two-way data binding when creating directives, for example:

```
app.module('main')
    .directive('dirTest'[function(){
        return {
            scope:{
                data:'='
            }
        }
    }])
```

Then we can use

```
<dir-test data="xx.data"></dir-test>
```

To pass the `xx.data` object to the directive, but it seems that this will make angular watch this expression.

This may be a waste of time once I do not care the change of the data or the data can hardly change.

Which means I need a one-way one-time data passwed to the directive, is this possible?

---

I ask this question because when I open the Batarang console, I found the `regularinterceptedexpression` cost too long and watch a lot of watchers. I think the page may run fast if I can remove some unused watchers.

I know there is a one-way from dom to directives by using `@`, however it seems that it just support string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, however you will need to eval `data` attribute and clone object yourself. The scope of this evaluation is going to be `scope.$parent` because this is the scope where the data comes from. If your directive doesn't need isolated scope (so you don't use `scope` config in the directive) then the attribute should be evaluated in the `scope`:

```
.directive('dirTest', [function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            something: '=' // something that might need two-way binding
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.data = angular.copy(scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.data));
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/nDzqWaVH9QkluFJknOfy?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

In angularjs if you create a directive with scope '`@'` then it will be Text bindings,which means you will be able to get the value of expression but making changes to it won't reflect back to the html page.so i believe if you create the directive in with scope `@` then it will do a job for you.

```
app.module('main')
    .directive('dirTest'[function(){
        return {
            scope:{
                data:'@'
            }
        }
    }]
```

)

```
<dir-test data={{xx.data}}></dir-test>
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  The mistake the OP is making is in thinking only a string can be provided to an '@' directive scope property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's one-time binding:

```
<dir-test data="::xx.data"></dir-test>
```

Note that it is available in Angular 1.3+. have a look at this article for more details: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html

Comment: In this case `::` will not help unfortunately, because two-way binding is set up differently in case of directive scope configuration. Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0JAVLNMAAIRXIVE9MTU2?p=preview